# how to release rhino from glassfish

Tags: glassfish, rhino

I have a web app using yuicompressor running on glassfish

however, when I run maven clean, I have the following error

Failed to delete C:.....\target\YUI-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\lib\js-1.7R2.jar -> [Help 1]

it is a bit strange, because if I deploy the app into tomcat, then no problem deleting the file

how to force glassfish divorce rhino?

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly some process is hanging on to the file.

Get handle.exe [1] and run it like so:

handle js-1

It should show the process.

Another way to check it out is to copy & paste the filename and delete it yourself manually.  If YOU can't delete it, neither can maven or GlassFish.

[1] http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655

Comment: doesn't help, it gives the "java.exe". I can confirm manual deleting the file is not possible ...